# System CPU usage in Live wallpaper

Tags: android

I'm making a live wallpaper that displays the overall CPU usage percentage. I'm using this code from one of the questions here. It works, but the wallpaper freezes for a few seconds because of the `Thread.sleep()`. And if I remove that, it doesn't display the correct values. How would I get the CPU usage, so that id doesn't interfere with the live wallapaper?

```
    private float readUsage() {
    try {
        RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/stat", "r");
        String load = reader.readLine();

        String[] toks = load.split(" ");

        long idle1 = Long.parseLong(toks[5]);
        long cpu1 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3]) + Long.parseLong(toks[4])
              + Long.parseLong(toks[6]) + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(360);
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        reader.seek(0);
        load = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();

        toks = load.split(" ");

        long idle2 = Long.parseLong(toks[5]);
        long cpu2 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3]) + Long.parseLong(toks[4])
            + Long.parseLong(toks[6]) + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);

        return (float)(cpu2 - cpu1) / ((cpu2 + idle2) - (cpu1 + idle1));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `Thread.sleep(~)`. Do the reading with a `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, long)` and update the UI from it.

Comment: But if I place the code in the `Runnable` I can't return the value.

Comment: Its kind of a workaround, but you can set a `boolean` flag from inside the `Runnable`. Compute `idle2` and `cpu2` inside the `Runnable`. In `readUsage()`, wait for the flag using `while(!booleanFlag) {}`. After the while loop, return `(float)(cpu2 - cpu1) / ((cpu2 + idle2) - (cpu1 + idle1))`. I don't if this is best practice though.